# Create custom certificate for dynamics portal using certbot/openssl

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, microsoft-dynamics, pfx

I need to create a custom certificate for my dynamics portal to use implicit grant flow. I create certificate with command

```
certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenge dns
```

I then create pfx with the openssl command

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out bundle.pfx -inkey privkey.pem -in cert.pem -certfile chain.pem -password pass:SOMEPASSWORDHERE
```

However I get the error when trying to upload it to the power platform admin centre

> The password entered is incorrect or the encryption method used by the
> certificate is not supported.

So then tried the following command to create the pfx with triple des using

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -descert -out bundle.pfx -inkey privkey.pem -in cert.pem -certfile chain.pem -password pass:SOMEPASSWORDHERE
```

But am still getting the same error. As far as I can see the certificate meets requirements of:

- Signed by a trusted certificate authority.
- Exported as a password-protected PFX file.
- Contains private key at least 2048 bits long.
- Contains all intermediate certificates in the certificate chain.
- Must be SHA2 enabled; SHA1 support is being removed from popular browsers.
- PFX file must be encrypted with TripleDES encryption. Power Apps portals doesn't support AES-256 encryption

The only thing I can think is the pfx isn't getting encrypted with 3des but looking at the openssl documentation the -descert command should take care of that. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you using OpenSSL 3.0.x? Unlike older/lower versions, that by default uses PBES2/AES-256 encryption for both keybag and certbag (and also PBMAC-sha256 for the integrity check). I don't know about dynamics, but I know some other Microsoft things like Azure are not compatible with this. Use `-legacy` to get the 'traditional' encryption of TripleDES for keybag and rc2-40 for certbag; use `-legacy` _and_ `-descert` to get TripleDES for both. `-descert` by itself selects TripleDES for certbag but not keybag, and so is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue and, as dave_thompson_085 replied, you need to use both `-legacy` and `-descert` for this to work. I've confirmed it does.