# Error with OpenSSL when devtools::check() the R package

Tags: r, windows, openssl, r-package

I'm currently working on a package in R, on of the functionalities is the creation of a new user. The function itself works fine, but the `devtools::test()` and the `devtools::check()` gives the following error :

```
Message: OpenSSL error in win32_load: could not load the shared library
Class:   simpleError/error/condition
Backtrace:
  1. testthat::expect_error(...)
       at test-new_user.R:2:4
  7. newUser::new_user(...)
 12. bcrypt::hashpw(password)
       at newUser/R/classUser.R:29:4
 13. bcrypt::gensalt()
 14. openssl::rand_bytes(16)
```

Here the example code

R/classUser.R

```
setClass("User",
         slots = c(
           user_id  = "character",
           name     = "character",
           email    = "character",
           password = "character"
         ))

setMethod(
  f = "initialize",
  signature = "User",
  definition = function(.Object,
                        user_id,
                        name,
                        email,
                        password){
    .Object@user_id  <- user_id
    .Object@name     <- name
    .Object@email    <- email
    .Object@password <- password
    return(.Object)
  }
)
```

R/new_user.R

```
#' new User
#' @importFrom uuid UUIDgenerate
#' @import bcrypt
#' @import methods
#' @param name character. name chosen by the user
#' @param email character. email of the user, must not already exist in database
#' @param password character. password chosen by the user
#'
#' @return User object
#' @export
new_user <- function(name, email, password){
  user <- new(Class = "User",
              user_id  = uuid::UUIDgenerate(),
              name     = name,
              email    = email,
              password = bcrypt::hashpw(password))
  return(user)
}
```

tests/testthat/test-new_user.R

```
test_that("new user", {
    expect_error(
      Aurelie <- new_user(
        name = "Aurélie",
        email = "Aurelie@tryharder",
        password = "Str0ngP4ssword++"
      ),
      NA
    )
})
```

I've tried to add `openssl` to Suggest section in `DESCRIPTION`, install OpenSLL on my device, add `Sys.setenv("R_TESTS" = "")` but nothing works.

Please help me understand what's going and maybe find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: I think openssl had a recent version increase. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74902418/create-custom-certificate-for-dynamics-portal-using-certbot-openssl